# Rename function's name inside button angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, function, angular9

On change select's function...
Depending on the selected option, I want to rename the 'functionX' dynamically...
**Frontend**

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedOp" (change)="selectedOption()">
   <option value={{op}} *ngFor="let op of Options">{{op}}</option>>
</select>

<button id="btnID" type="submit" (click)="functionX()">
 Button
</button>
```

**Backend**

I've been trying this using js...

```
Options = ['Function1', 'Function2'];

selectedOp;

selectedOption(){
    switch (this.selectedOp) {
      case 'Function1':
          const btn = document.getElementById('btnID');
          btn.setAttribute('(click)', 'function1()');
      break;
      case 'Function2':
          const btn = document.getElementById('btnID');
          btn.setAttribute('(click)', 'function2()');
      break
}
```

Then this error happens...

```
ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '(click)' is not a valid attribute name..
```

If you guys know of a better way to do this, I'd appreciate your sharing :)

Comment: Probably better if you explain why you would need this..

Comment: @MikeOne I already edited the post, thanks for comment :)

Comment: You know you can just have a generic function and pass in any component or local template based variable.. right..?

Comment: Thanks!! @MikeOne I didn't think in that solution, it worked! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
selectedOption(){
switch (this.selectedOp) {
  case 'Function1':
      this.funciton1();
  break;
  case 'Function2':
      this.function2();
  break
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to other users with similar issues.